# Ruby Sinatra Hash nested in Array

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am a bit of ruby nooby and can't seem to grasp, what appears to be a hash nested in array?!

if I run the following:

```
widgets = Sinatra::Application.settings.history
widgets.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  puts value
end
```

I get the following result:

```
sales31
data: {"text":"Moeslein Nate","dataImg":"/vinD.jpg","id":"sales31","updatedAt":1511232577}
```

However; when I attempt to extract only the values using the key, I'm met with an error:

```
widgets = Sinatra::Application.settings.history
widgets.each do |key|
  puts key[:data]
end
```

Met with Error
`TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

That led me to believe it was an array with a nested hash, so I tried:

```
widgets = Sinatra::Application.settings.history
widgets.each do |key|
  puts key[0]
end
```

Which just prints the keys again
`sales30`
`sales31`

and if I try and extract nested data:

```
widgets = Sinatra::Application.settings.history
widgets.each do |key|
  puts key[0][:data]
end
```

Back to `Type Error`

and just the first letter of the key this time:

```
widgets = Sinatra::Application.settings.history
widgets.each do |key|
  puts key[0][0]
end
```

Could someone elaborate on the best/most feasible way for me to parse this data as so I can use the KEY to extract particular values:

```
widgets[sales31][text]
```

as to where it would print the actual text:

```
Moeslein Nate
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: i think i can help you, but can you say exactly what the result should be? The `each` iterator, by the way, works differently on hashes when the block is given one argument (in which case it becomes a `[<key>, <val>]` array or two arguments (in which case they are set to key and val respectively)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm looking to be able to dynamically access the elements like so:
Hash[Key][data:][text:] and have the text portion returned: "Moeslein Nate"
Hash[Key][data:][dataImg:] should return "/vinD.jpg"

I'd like to get at the values nested under data: but using logic as so I can get them using the key to ensure my key values match accordingly!

Comment: based on your ruby version, or adding `activesupport` as dependency you can use `transform_keys!`. thus you can normalize all your keys to be in same type (e.g. symbol)

Comment: Thank you @marmeladze, that's one I was not aware of!

Comment: @marmeladze you just caused me to look up the docs and there is also a public method `deep_symbolize_keys!` that will do it recursively. It also has '`deep_stringify_keys!` to do the opposite. Very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the fact that you have another layer of Hash in "data"

So the correct way to access it is:

```
widgets["sales31"]["data"]["text"]
```

thus,

```
widgets = Sinatra::Application.settings.history
widgets.each do |key, val|
  puts val["text"]
end
```

since the value of `val` is:

```
"data": {"text":"Moeslein Nate","dataImg":"/vinD.jpg","id":"sales31","updatedAt":1511232577}
```

which is a Hash itself.
So widgets is a hash of:

```
widgets == {"sales31":  "data": {"text": "Moeslein Nate", "dataImg": "/vinD.jpg", "id": "sales31", "updatedAt" :1511232577} }

widgets["sales31"] == { "data": {"text": "Moeslein Nate", "dataImg": "/vinD.jpg", "id": "sales31", "updatedAt" :1511232577} }

widgets["sales31"]["data"] == {"text": "Moeslein Nate", "dataImg": "/vinD.jpg", "id": "sales31", "updatedAt" :1511232577}

widgets["sales31"]["data"]["text"] == "Moeslein Nate"
```

Basically a hash within a hash within a hash. You are not very clear on how you want your information formatted but you could do:

```
widgets = Sinatra::Application.settings.history
widgets.each do |key, val|
  puts "widgets[#{key}][#{val.keys[0]}] = #{val[valkeys[0]]["text"]}"   
end
#=> "widgets["sales31"]["data"] = Moeslein Nate"
```

Now that's not the prettiest way to do it but since you asked for a programmatic solution it get the job done without naming hash keys explicitly. It could be simplified to this if it works for you:

```
widgets = Sinatra::Application.settings.history
widgets.each do |key, val|    
  puts "widgets[#{key}]["data"] = #{val["data"]["text"]}" 
end
```

UPDATE:
Thanks to @marmeladze comment I found the method `deep_symbolize_keys` it can be used with the `!` to modify the original if you prefer. I would do something like:

```
my_widgets = widgets.deep_symbolize_keys
my_widgets = Sinatra::Application.settings.history
my_widgets.each do |key, val|    
  puts "widgets[#{key}][:data] = #{val[:data][:text]}" 
end
```

It just seems cleaner to me to not mix key types unless you need to.

Comment: Thanks a ton man, this solved it for me! Appreciate the detail! I was also able to pull off a sort using the following:
`mySortedHash = myJobsHash.sort_by { |k,v| "#{v['monthTotals']}"}.reverse`

Cheers!